# How to create a fork of a parent repository using Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How can we create a new repository copying all the contents from a parent repository? I have tried forking an existing repository, but the REST API is throwing 400 Bad Request exception.

The sample request provided in the Microsoft document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#create-a-fork-of-a-parent-repository) is not working as expected and is throwing below exception.

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "A team project ID or name is required in the URL or request body.\r\nParameter name: ProjectReference",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer",
    "typeKey": "InvalidArgumentValueException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create a fork of a parent repository using Azure DevOps REST API?

I could reproduce this issue with the sample request body.

To resolve this issue, please try to **replace the `name` with `ID` of the project**:

```
{
  "name": "forkRepository",
  "project": {
    "id": "MyFirstProject_ID"
  },
  "parentRepository": {
    "name": "MyFirstRepo",
    "project": {
      "id": "MyFirstProject_ID"
    }
  }
}
```

My test result:

[image]

And the fork repo:

[image]